# Magento2 Get a list of all cms static blocks

Tags: magento2, resource-model

I have created a new widget programatically and i would like to create a custom source model with dropdown values all the cms static blocks.

Is that possible? How can i get a list of all the static blocks ?

> app/code/Ves/CustomWidget/etc/widget.xml

```
<parameter name="gender" xsi:type="select" source_model="Ves\CustomWidget\Model\Config\Source\StaticBlock" visible="true" sort_order="10" >
            <label translate="true">Static Block</label>
</parameter>
```

And my Source Model

> app/code/Ves/CustomWidget/Model/Config/Source/StaticBlock.php

```
namespace Ves\CustomWidget\Model\Config\Source;
class StaticBlock implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

   public function toOptionArray()
   {
       // Get all cms static blocks and return them by id/Title 
       // instead of hardcoded values
       return [
       ['value' => 'static_block_id_1', 'label' => __('Static block Title 1')],
       ['value' => 'static_block_id_1', 'label' => __('Static block Title 1')]];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do a dependency injection of Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory class in your constructor

```
public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
        ...
    ) {
        $this->_blockFactory = $blockFactory;
        ...
    }
```

Then you can use the following code in your function to get the collection of blocks

```
$this->_blockFactory->create()->getCollection();
```

You can then use the above collection to iterate!

Comment: You are welcome Sir! glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

This is my version as a source model used inside system.xml file

`<source_model>Vendor\Modulename\Model\Config\Source\CmsBlocks</source_model>`

```
namespace Vendor\Modulename\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class CmsBlocks implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var BlockRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository;
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * CmsBlocks constructor.
     * @param BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Return array of options as value-label pairs
     *
     * @return array Format: array(array('value' => '<value>', 'label' => '<label>'), ...)
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function toOptionArray(): array
    {
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $cmsBlocks = $this->blockRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems(); //LocalizedException

        $arrResult = [];

        foreach ($cmsBlocks as $block) {
            $arrResult[] = ['value' => $block->getIdentifier(), 'label' => $block->getTitle()];
        }
        return $arrResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Magento has a built-in class `Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Collection` with the `toOptionArray` method. So, no need to implement it.

Just use the snippets below according to your needs and scopes:

For config [ `etc/adminhtml/system.xml` ]

```
<field id="static_block_txt" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
    <label>Select Static Block</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Collection</source_model>
</field>
```

For widget [ `etc/widget.xml` ]

```
<parameter name="static_block_txt" xsi:type="select" visible="true"
            source_model="Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Block\Collection">
    <label translate="true">Select Static Block</label>
</parameter>
```